# Entity Framework abusing sp_execsql on AddRange in DB first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a DB first model using EF 6.1.

I need to do massive imports of data. In Mysql, splitting the entire stream into smaller collections of 500 elements and `AddRange`-ing them results in reasonable insertion performance (I also tweaked the code by making it parallel and benchmarking the number of threads).

When running on SQL Server, the same code produces a horrible mess of performance. SQL Server profiler shows that EF tries to insert every single entity as a separate INSERT, but not using plain old `INSERT`, instead relying on `sp_executesql`

Example:

```
    public int Save(IList<BaseEntity> entities)
    {
        using (var dataContext = GetDataContext())
        {
                using (var tx = dataContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
            dataContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            dataContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            dataContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            var sa = entities.OfType<A>();
            var sd = entities.OfType<D>();
            var se = entities.OfType<E>();
            var sf = entities.OfType<F>();
            var sg = entities.OfType<G>();
            var sh = entities.OfType<H>();

            dataContext.sezione_a.AddRange(sa);
            dataContext.sezione_d.AddRange(sd);
            dataContext.sezione_e.AddRange(se);
            dataContext.sezione_f.AddRange(sf);
            dataContext.sezione_g.AddRange(sg);
            dataContext.sezione_h.AddRange(sh);

            int ret = dataContext.SaveChanges();

                 tx.Commit();
            return ret
            }
        }
    }
```

This because my list contains a mixture of several entities, but the entire list counts up to 500. More threads invoke this method at the same time.

When I run profiler, I can see

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[sezione_a]([A01], [A01a], [A01b], [A02], [A03], [A11], [A12], [A12a], [A12b], [A12c], [A21], [A22], [A23], [A24], [A25], [A31], [A31a], [A31b], [A32], [A33], [A33a], [A33b], [A33c], [A34], [A41], [A42], [A43], [A51], [A52], [A53], [A54], [A54a], [A54b], [A54c], [B11], [B12], [B13], [B14], [B15], [Z0], [progA], [utente])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22, @23, @24, @25, @26, @27, @28, @29, @30, @31, @32, @33, @34, @35, @36, @37, @38, @39, @40, @41)
',N'@0 varchar(13),@1 varchar(2),@2 varchar(11),@3 varchar(1),@4 varchar(20),@5 varchar(6),@6 varchar(38),@7 varchar(6),@8 varchar(30),@9 varchar(2),@10 varchar(8),@11 varchar(1),@12 varchar(1),@13 varchar(4),@14 varchar(2),@15 varchar(13),@16 varchar(2),@17 varchar(11),@18 varchar(3),@19 varchar(38),@20 varchar(6),@21 varchar(30),@22 varchar(2),@23 varchar(50),@24 varchar(25),@25 varchar(1),@26 varchar(1),@27 varchar(8),@28 varchar(2),@29 varchar(12),@30 varchar(29),@31 varchar(1),@32 varchar(8),@33 varchar(20),@34 varchar(1),@35 varchar(3),@36 varchar(1),@37 decimal(18,2),@38 decimal(18,2),@39 varchar(69),@40 bigint,@41 int',@0='0907084500011',@1='09',@2='07084500011',@3='1',@4='20110209100276666600',[...]
```

This is repeated for every single record.

I have examined other bulk insert strategies, but since my application **needs** to be portable along MS SQL and Mysql I can't rely on additional libraries that rely themselves on SqlBulkCopy. I mean I want to use the same code.

Mysql looks like squashing the inserts into a single `INSERT` for each of the 6 tables. SQL Server looks not.

I have also checked my edmx model and, after reading about `varchar` vs `nvarchar` issues, I normalized all columns to `varchar` and `Unicode="false"` directly into the xml.

But that did not work.

What can I do to have EF squash `INSERT`s into a single statement and get decent performance? 200 seconds for 500 rows are unacceptable.

Comment: Squashing multiple statements in one batch isn't going to speed things up much, because the T-SQL parser isn't terribly efficient to begin with (and beyond a certain string size performance actually *drops*, precipitously). I mean yes, it helps, but not as much as you think. Combining those inserts into a *transaction*, on the other hand, is a lot more effective, since it cuts down on log writes and speeds up roundtrips. Wrap things in a `TransactionScope` and see if that does anything for you.

Comment: That did change nothing. Sorry

Comment: That seems rather improbable, unless the code was *already* using a transaction. Does a profiler trace show a `BEGIN TRANSACTION`?

Comment: I have edited my question with new transaction code using EF's Database.BeginTransaction API. Profiler shows no trace of begin transaction though

Comment: You do need to have `.SaveChanges` within the transaction. Nothing is actually happening on the database until you call that.

Comment: My mistake in editing the code **here**. The sample does not 100% reflect my real code, but SaveChanges occurs **within** transaction. Re-editing to show

Comment: You could try if `EntityFramework.Utilities` -> https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities can be of help. I have used it with success in a past project. It is targeted for SQL Server, with supposed fallbacks for other db types (which in your case runs fast already, if I understand correctly).

Comment: I have tried that but unfortunately it crashes internally. I could report a bug to the author, but I doubt the project is still maintained and I could get a fix in reasonable time (maybe the DB-first model itself is the culprit). I could otherwise debug it but I am afraid I may end up digging too long. I have an alternate solution we decided to keep as **last resort**: using SQL Server native bulk load from file. That worked in the past, was ugly code, but if we have to revive that bad code from the ashes, then be it. sad face

Comment: Entity Framework uses ADO.NET, and when using paramterized SQL, sp_executesql is always used - why does that worry you? Batching INSERTs is not supported with EF 6, it is available in EF Core

Comment: IMHO, @ErikEJ 's comment was good as an answer too. Anyway it **worries** me a lot because I have simply to insert 1M+ record cross-platformly. And SqlBulkLoader is SQLServer-specific only. As in my previous comment, I can, but do not like, splitting insertion mode for Mysql and Sqlserver

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of cross-system database development. Unfortunately, while most every system has facilities for it, there is no *standard* interface for bulk loading data. Simply inserting 1M+ rows is easy; doing it quickly is not.

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ I have undeleted my reply, and added info about alternatives for EF6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework uses ADO.NET, and when using paramterized SQL, sp_executesql is always used - why does that worry you? Batching INSERTs is not supported with EF 6, it is available in EF Core. For quick, bulk updates use ADO.NET with Table Valued Parameters og the SqlClient SqlBulkCopy API

Comment: IMHO, this should be a comment, not an answer.